# Fluent NHibernate mapping for UDT Oracle Objects

Tags: oracle, orm, oracle11g, fluent-nhibernate, user-defined-types

As a predefined conditions I have multiple database sources to deal with.

Also I have a UDT – user defined types objects in part of this databases ( the UDT’s also have children inside)  .

As a methodology I am a believer of using the ORM-object relational mapping to connect to DB’s .

In the past I’ve successfully implemented Fluent NHibernate library to connect to Oracle. 
I’ve found a workaround for the Multiple Databases , even though the solution may be more elegant in future.

Nevertheless  , I still can’t find a solution for mapping the UDT’s .

I think that it should be something like implementation of IUserType or ICompositeUserType .

If there is a known framework presenting option for a full ORM , including UDT’s handle it also can be a solution in our case.

I’ve checked out the EF of oracle (that is very premature) and also DevArt (that doesn’t handle UDT’s) as a possible solutions.

The ODP.Net is the only possible way right now and it’s not too friendly for the developers to use – no LINQ support , no context to begin with.

If you or any of your colleagues can help with some samples of the implementation of this kind of mapping it will be very appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I feel your pain, working with ODP.NET is not a pleasant experience at all. DevArt dotConnect supports UDT's. [DevArt Objects documentation](http://www.devart.com/dotconnect/oracle/docs/Objects.html)

Comment: [Devart #27686]: can not write on forums from support support@devart.com sender-time Sent at 2:16 PM (GMT+03:00). Current time there: 9:44 AM. 

Unfortunately, we are unable to provide Oracle UDT support in Entity Framework.

Best regards,
Andrey
Devart Team
www.devart.com

Ticket Details
===================
Ticket ID: 27686
Department: Direct Team
Priority: Medium
Status: Closed

Comment: The answer from Devart was -

Unfortunately, we are unable to provide Oracle UDT support in Entity Framework.

Comment: aha, but their standard ado.net can handle udt, both typed and untyped. The typed udt is same principle as in the odp.net, the untyped is basically a collection of properties in OracleObject object. Still a bit easier to use than the odp.net provider.